# How can I place a button to the right of a 2D-buttonarray?

Tags: c#, forms, button, grid

I'm a beginner to C# and are trying to make a MineSweeper game. So far I've come a long way, but I'm missing some details. I'm making a grid of buttons in a 2D-array.

Here are the code for the button array:

```
            btnArray = new Button[rows, cols];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
              for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {    
                    btnArray[i, j] = new Button();

                    btnArray[i, j].Width = 40;
                    btnArray[i, j].Height = 40;
                    btnArray[i, j].Margin = new (0);

                    btnArray[i, j].Left = xPos;
                    btnArray[i, j].Top = yPos;
                    btnArray[i, j].BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    btnArray[i, j].MouseDown += btnArray_MouseDown;
                    
                    hasbomb = bombeListe[o];
                    if (hasbomb)
                    {
                        plassertBomber++;
                    }
                    btnArray[i, j].Tag = new Cell(i, j, hasbomb, false);

                    _buttonForm.Controls.Add(btnArray[i, j]);
                    xPos += btnArray[i, j].Width;
                    if (m == cols)
                    {
                        xPos = 0;
                        yPos += btnArray[i, j].Width;
                        m = 0;
                    }
                    m++;
                    o++;
                }
            }
```

What I want to do is add a pause button to the right of the grid, lets say the top/right. The problem is that I have 3 different difficulties (Easy, Medium, Hard) and a custom, where the player can choose the size of the grid, and when i change between them the pause button changes places.

(See pictures)
[Easy mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2gb0.png)
[Custom mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2vJa.png)

Here are the code for the pause button:

```
      public void Generate_buttons()
      {
          Button pause = new();
          int xpos = (btnArray.GetLength(0) * 42);

          pause.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;

          //int pos = (btnArray[btnArray.GetLength(0), 0].Location.X);
          pause.Text = ("Pause");
          pause.Width = 130;
          pause.Height = 40;
          pause.AutoSize = true;
          pause.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
          pause.Margin = new(0);
          pause.Left = xpos;

          _buttonForm.Controls.Add(pause);
      }
```

Thanks for all the help I can get:) Btw, I'm a beginner, so I know my code is not that good probably, but I would appreciate any tips!:D

(I'm new to stack overflow aswell, so if I need to now some tips for asking questions I would like all the help I could get. Can you only have 2 pictures in a question btw?)
Thanks!

Comment: First, I think you have an error here `yPos += btnArray[i, j].Width;`: probably it should be `yPos += btnArray[i, j].Height;`

Comment: The I think you should use `int xpos = (btnArray.GetLength(1) * 40);`; anyway cella size should be declared as a constant you can reuse so you don't have to use a fixed number here.
Form should also be resized accordingly to grid dimension.
There would be tons of improvements, but you're just starting, so that's ok!

Comment: @Marco Thank you so much! I changed `yPos += btnArray[i, j].Width;` to .Height. And then i used `int xpos = (btnArray.GetLength(1) * 40);` which fixed the problem! Thanks again:D

Comment: Any tips for some improvments?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have an error here:
`yPos += btnArray[i, j].Width;`: probably it should be `yPos += btnArray[i, j].Height;`

The I think you should use int `xpos = (btnArray.GetLength(1) * 40);`

Anyway cells size should be declared as a constant so you don't have to use a fixed number when declaring cells and buttons.